# how make counter to continuous after app restarted in qt

Tags: qt

I am using qtcreator locking for a way to save my data
if i restart my app it continue from last value not restart to 0
its only part of the code

```
void Form::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: You could use a text file or depending on your use case QSettings: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can either save it to a file of your choice: [Writing Integers to a .txt file in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815139/writing-integers-to-a-txt-file-in-c)

Or you can use Qt Settings file: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html

Or if you start to have more information and you also what to save relationships between your data, you can start looking at Databases. A simple and local DBMS is Sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/index.html